# Треугольник на css без заливки

Tags: css

Как сделать такой треугольник на css?
При этом треугольник по высоте растянут, не равносторонний
Посоветуйте, если эту стрелку нужно показывать только при наведении на пункт меню, нужно ли здесь использовать svg? Пунктов меню может быть очень много из-за вложенности
Получается в конце каждого пункта нужно вставлять svg?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">title</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">title</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">title</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#">title</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">title</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">title</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
            <li><a href="#">title</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Обязательно CSS? Может стоит использовать, например, SVG?

Comment: @Alex Chermenin, а посоветуйте, эта стрелка будет на выпадающем меню при наведении на пункт меню. Пунктов меню может быть много, т.к. будет несколько уровней вложенности. Если использовать svg, не будет ли это сильно накладно для dom ?

Comment: @Alex Chermenin, подскажите, получается что в конце каждого пункта нужно вставлять svg?

Comment: в каждом месте, где нужно использовать стрелку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;  
}
.arrow-right:before,
.arrow-right:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 1px;
  background: tomato;
}
.arrow-right:before{  
  margin: -10px 0 0 -12px;  
  transform: rotate(55deg);  
}
.arrow-right:after{  
  top: auto; bottom: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 -10px -12px;  
  transform: rotate(-55deg);  
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

Comment: я обновил вопрос. Подскажите, если нужно использовать эту стрелку при ховере на пункт меню, тогда уже лучше использовать svg, чем `<div class="arrow-right"></div>` ?

Comment: @word - какая анимация со стрелкой должна быть при ховере?

Comment: анимации со стрелкой нет. Стрелка появляется только при ховере

Comment: @word https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qxup8g7w/ такой вариант подойдет?

Comment: благодарю, то что надо

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не использовать svg?

```html
<svg>
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" 
      points="0,0 4,6 0,12"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: если нужно использовать эту стрелку для ховера во всплывающем меню, как правильно сделать? использовать svg? пунктов меню может быть очень много. Т.е. навели курсор на пункт меню, появляется эта стрелка вконце пункта меню, также появляется вложенное меню

Comment: получается в конце каждого пункта нужно вставлять svg?

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать `css`, то только псевдо-элементами `:before` и `:after`

```css
.arrow-right{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.arrow-right:before{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow-right:after{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow-left{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 130px;
}

.arrow-left:before{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow-left:after{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
```